# How do I make python-bottle log send its stdout to a file?

Tags: python, logging, bottle, python-daemon

Bottle has nice `access_log` output that I want to log to a file.

How do I use `daemon` and put that in a file somewhere?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from bottle import route, run
import daemon

@route('/foo')
def foo():
  return template('bar')

log = open('/dev/shm/access_log', 'a')
with daemon.DaemonContext(stdout=log):
  run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

It backgrounds and bottle works but I get nothing in `/dev/shm/access_log`.

Comment: try stderr instead of stdout. i doubt it's writing log messages to stdout.

Comment: Well, you're right. But that makes it next to worthless for me. Apache it is.

Comment: The built in development server should not be used for production anyway! It can't even serve more than one concurrent request.

Comment: @aychedee: why do you assume I'm using it for production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bottle prints to `stderr`, not `stdout`.

```
log = open('/dev/shm/access_log', 'a')
with daemon.DaemonContext(stderr=log):
  run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```